# Invoke multiple aws services from lambda function in java

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a use case where I want to invoke multiple AWS services from an AWS Lambda function written using the Lambda runtime Java API. For example, I would like to invoke SNS, and Pinpoint. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Your post isn't even in the form of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Lambda function that invokes multiple AWS Services by using the Java Lambda runtime API. This AWS tutorial steps you through the process and then uses the Lambda functions to create a workflow using AWS Step Functions.

[image]

[Using AWS Step Functions and the AWS SDK for Java to build workflows that sends notifications over multiple channels](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels)